# How to create a 5-level tree diagram and highlight certain branches

Tags: tikz-pgf

Currently I am trying to create a tree diagram. I need to fit this into a beamer slide. This is what I did so far:

```
\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance=60mm/#1}]
\node[circle,draw] (0){$0$}
  child {node[circle,draw] (A) {$A$}
    child {node[circle,draw] (B) {$B$}
      child {node[circle,draw](C) {C}
        child {node[circle,draw] (D) {$D$}}
        child {node[circle,draw] (E) {$E$}}
            } 
      child {node[circle,draw](F){$F$}}
          }
    child {node[circle,draw](G) {$G$}
      child {node[circle,draw](H) {$H$}}
      child {node[circle,draw](I) {$I$}}
          }
        }
  child {node[circle,draw](J) {$J$}
    child {node[circle,draw](K) {$K$}
      child {node[circle,draw](L) {$L$}}
      child {node[circle,draw](M){$M$}}
          }
  child {node [circle,draw] (N) {$N$}
   % child {node[circle,draw](O) {$O$}}
    child {node[circle,draw](P){$P$}
      child {node [circle,draw](Q) {$Q$}}
      child {node [circle,draw](R) {$R$}
% ----------------------------------------
%text on the right -----------------------
       child [grow=right] {node (q) {\void} edge from parent[draw=none]
          child [grow=right] {node (q) {4. Stufe} edge from parent[draw=none]
            child [grow=up] {node (r) {3. Stufe} edge from parent[draw=none]
              child [grow=up] {node (s) {2. Stufe} edge from parent[draw=none]
                child [grow=up] {node (t) {1. Stufe} edge from parent[draw=none]
                  child [grow=up] {node (u) {Start} edge from parent[draw=none]}
% ----------------------------------------
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

% Wahrscheinlichkeiten der Pfade
\path (0) -- (A) node [midway, left]  {\; $\frac{o}{a}$ \;};
\path (0) -- (J) node [midway, right] {\; $\frac{o}{j}$ \;};

\path (A) -- (B) node [midway, left] {\; $\frac{a}{b}$ \;};

\path (B) -- (C) node [midway, left] {\; $\frac{b}{c}$ \;};
\path (B) -- (F) node [midway, right] {\; $\frac{b}{f}$ \;};
 \path (C) -- (D) node [midway, left] {\; $\frac{c}{d}$ \;};
 \path (C) -- (E) node [midway, right] {\; $\frac{c}{e}$ \;};

\path (A) -- (G) node [midway, right] {\; $\frac{a}{g}$ \;};
 \path (G) -- (H) node [midway, left] {\; $\frac{g}{h}$ \;};
 \path (G) -- (I) node [midway, right] {\; $\frac{g}{i}$ \;};

\path (J) -- (K) node [midway, left] {\; $\frac{j}{k}$ \;};
 \path (K) -- (L) node [midway, left] {\; $\frac{k}{l}$ \;};
 \path (K) -- (M) node [midway, right] {\; $\frac{k}{m}$ \;};

\path (J) -- (N) node [midway, right] {\; $\frac{j}{n}$ \;};
 \path (N) -- (P) node [midway, right] {\; $\frac{n}{p}$ \;};
   \path (P) -- (Q) node [midway, left] {\; $\frac{p}{q}$ \;};
   \path (P) -- (R) node [midway, right] {\; $\frac{p}{r}$ \;};    

\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Now i got two questions: How can I add a fifth level to my diagram and how does it fit to a beamer slide? And the second: How can I highlight certain branches of the diagram in a different color?

Comment: Please complete your example. If it needs to fit a beamer slide, it needs the `beamer` class etc. and we need the theme you are using etc. The code does not compile even when I add the obvious class and package to the file.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "highlight certain branches"? Do you mean how to colorize some edges of the tree?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You add a fifth level just the way you added the other levels. Of course, it has to fit on the slide!

`forest` is especially good at drawing compact trees. Here's a version using this package:

[image: compact forest]

This actually uses a `forest` style which I wrote as an experiment. The code for the example is

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etex,prooftrees}% remove etex if unneeded

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \fbox{\begin{forest}
    proof tree,
    no line numbering,
    single branches,
    for tree={
      circle,
      draw,
      math content,
      minimum size=2em,
      inner sep=1.5pt,
      before drawing tree={
        if level=0{}{
          if n'=1{
            edge label/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={node [midway, right=.5em] {\ensuremath{\frac{#2}{#1}}}}{content()}{content("!u")},
          }{
            edge label/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={node [midway, left=.5em] {\ensuremath{\frac{#2}{#1}}}}{content()}{content("!u")},
          },
        }{}
      },
      l sep+=3mm,
    },
    [, phantom
      [0, name=0, just=Start
        [A, name=A, just={1. Stufe}
          [B, name=B, just={2. Stufe}
            [C, name=C, just={3. Stufe}
              [D, name=D, just={4. Stufe}]
              [E, name=E]
            ]
            [F, name=F]
          ]
          [G, name=G
            [H, name=H]
            [I, name=I]
          ]
        ]
        [J, name=J
          [K, name=K
            [L, name=L]
            [M, name=M]
          ]
          [N, name=N
            [P, name=P
              [Q, name=Q
                [S, name=S, just={5. Stufe}]
                [T, name=T]
              ]
              [R, name=R]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You do not need `etex` unless your TeX installation is very up-to-date, and you will not need it in a few days when the bug fix propagates through CTAN. If you have an updated TeX Live 2015, you will need it temporarily.

**The code for the `prooftrees` package is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244067/expansion-in-forest/244187#244187). Save as `prooftrees.sty` in the same directory as your `.tex` file.**

To colour branches, you can use `for tree={<colour>, edge={<colour>}}`. For example, if I add to the node `A` as follows

```
, for tree={green!50!black, edge={green!50!black}}
```

and to `K` as follows

```
, for tree={blue, edge={blue}}
```

reverting the `G` branch to black with

```
, for tree={black, edge={black}}
```

then I get

[image: colouring branches]

Complete code (excluding prooftrees.sty):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etex,prooftrees}% remove etex if unneeded

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \fbox{\begin{forest}
    proof tree,
    no line numbering,
    single branches,
    for tree={
      circle,
      draw,
      math content,
      minimum size=2em,
      inner sep=1.5pt,
      before drawing tree={
        if level=0{}{
          if n'=1{
            edge label/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={node [midway, right=.5em] {\ensuremath{\frac{#2}{#1}}}}{content()}{content("!u")},
          }{
            edge label/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={node [midway, left=.5em] {\ensuremath{\frac{#2}{#1}}}}{content()}{content("!u")},
          },
        }{}
      },
      l sep+=3mm,
    },
    [, phantom
      [0, name=0, just=Start
        [A, name=A, just={1. Stufe}, for tree={green!50!black, edge={green!50!black}}
          [B, name=B, just={2. Stufe}
            [C, name=C, just={3. Stufe}
              [D, name=D, just={4. Stufe}]
              [E, name=E]
            ]
            [F, name=F]
          ]
          [G, name=G, for tree={black, edge={black}}
            [H, name=H]
            [I, name=I]
          ]
        ]
        [J, name=J
          [K, name=K, for tree={blue, edge={blue}}
            [L, name=L]
            [M, name=M]
          ]
          [N, name=N
            [P, name=P
              [Q, name=Q
                [S, name=S, just={5. Stufe}]
                [T, name=T]
              ]
              [R, name=R]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

## EDIT

If you don't want the edges to originate from a single point on the parent, you can add `parent anchor=,` to the `for tree={...}` invocation:

```
...
for tree={
  circle,
  draw,
  parent anchor=,
  math content,
  minimum size=2em,
  inner sep=1.5pt,
  ...
```

to get

[image: edges from different points on parent]

A similar approach would use `justtrees` which is a simplified version of `prooftrees`. The code is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247657/how-to-typeset-a-minmax-algorithm-tree/247720#247720). Save it as `justtrees.sty` in the same directory as your `.tex` file.

The output is essentially the same but the package is using somewhat simpler code and might, possibly, compile a bit faster (I'm not sure).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etex,justtrees}% remove etex if unneeded

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \fbox{\begin{forest}
    just tree,
    for tree={
      circle,
      draw,
      parent anchor=,
      math content,
      minimum size=2em,
      inner sep=1.5pt,
      before drawing tree={
        if level=0{}{
          if n'=1{
            edge label/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={node [midway, right=.5em] {\ensuremath{\frac{#2}{#1}}}}{content()}{content("!u")},
          }{
            edge label/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={node [midway, left=.5em] {\ensuremath{\frac{#2}{#1}}}}{content()}{content("!u")},
          },
        }{}
      },
      l sep+=3mm,
    },
    [, phantom
      [0, name=0, right just=Start
        [A, name=A, right just={1. Stufe}, for tree={green!50!black, edge={green!50!black}}
          [B, name=B, right just={2. Stufe}
            [C, name=C, right just={3. Stufe}
              [D, name=D, right just={4. Stufe}]
              [E, name=E]
            ]
            [F, name=F]
          ]
          [G, name=G, for tree={black, edge={black}}
            [H, name=H]
            [I, name=I]
          ]
        ]
        [J, name=J
          [K, name=K, for tree={blue, edge={blue}}
            [L, name=L]
            [M, name=M]
          ]
          [N, name=N
            [P, name=P
              [Q, name=Q
                [S, name=S, right just={5. Stufe}]
                [T, name=T]
              ]
              [R, name=R]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: just tree with right justifications]

## EDIT

In response to the discussion in comment, `\scalebox{<scale>}{\begin{forest}...\end{forest}}` can be used to scale the tree. However, making it half the size will make it difficult or impossible for the audince to read. Removing the fractions on the edges will help a little bit. If some of these fractions are really essential, they can be added directly using `edge node` or a style `my label` can be created to create the fractions based on node content when required.

For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etex,justtrees}% remove etex if unneeded

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \fbox{\scalebox{.5}{\begin{forest}
    my label/.style={
      if n'=1{
        edge label/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={node [midway, right=.5em] {\ensuremath{\frac{##2}{##1}}}}{content()}{content("!u")},
      }{
        edge label/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={node [midway, left=.5em] {\ensuremath{\frac{##2}{##1}}}}{content()}{content("!u")},
      },
    },
    just tree,
    for tree={
      circle,
      draw,
      parent anchor=,
      math content,
      minimum size=2em,
      inner sep=1.5pt,
      l sep+=3mm,
    },
    [, phantom
      [0, name=0, right just=Start
        [A, name=A, right just={1. Stufe}, for tree={green!50!black, edge={green!50!black}}
          [B, name=B, right just={2. Stufe}, my label
            [C, name=C, right just={3. Stufe}
              [D, name=D, right just={4. Stufe}]
              [E, name=E]
            ]
            [F, name=F]
          ]
          [G, name=G, for tree={black, edge={black}}
            [H, name=H]
            [I, name=I]
          ]
        ]
        [J, name=J
          [K, name=K, for tree={blue, edge={blue}}, my label
            [L, name=L]
            [M, name=M]
          ]
          [N, name=N
            [P, name=P
              [Q, name=Q
                [S, name=S, my label, right just={5. Stufe}]
                [T, name=T, my label]
              ]
              [R, name=R]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}}}
\end{frame}
```

[image: mini-tree]

Note that I really do ***not*** recommend making the tree this small unless either you wish to annoy your audience or you know that your audience will consist entirely of bright-eyed eagles.

Comment: +1. Nice. (and some more dummy text so it lets me post my comment).

Comment: Any plans on making `prooftrees` available from CTAN?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I'm not sure whether I should. I  would at least like somebody to test it before I do that. Right now, I'm the only person who has used it as far as I know. There's actually a second version, `justtrees` which I probably should have used for this answer and which is very similar. (It doesn't do automated line numbering as `prooftrees` can.) Also, I wasn't sure whether the promised beta of the new `forest` might break things. I really would like a way to automatically add the `phantom` root node, but I've not yet figured out a way to do it.

Comment: If you want to, I would volunteer for testing the package. Depending on the actual scope of the package you could then decide if it is worth to upload it to CTAN, but at first sight, I'd say it is worth it.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Update code is [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244067/expansion-in-forest/244187#244187). Almost certainly an abuse of the SE site, but whatever. I don't have any documentation at the moment, though. I'll see if I can find time to write some. It is not really intended to be all that customisable. However, you can specify explicit single branches (default is not), no line numbering (default is numbered) and perhaps one or two other things I've forgotten about. It is rather messy.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at it and let you know. Anything in particular that you'd like me to focus on?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Not really. Maybe the `\NewEnviron` bit I just added, which looks dodgy to me. Mostly, I just assume it must break horribly given it is my code. The only packages I've released onto an unsuspecting public have all been font-related and that's all fairly standard stuff. (Not to say I can't screw it up, but the number of ways in which I can screw it up is rather more limited.) Most of the stuff there is not in the LaTeX code at all, and you can *see* if your code has put things in all the expected places ;). So it doesn't feel quite so cruel to inflict it on the innocent.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks for playing guinea pig! I'm pretty sure it can't eat your hard drive or anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would it be possible to scale the complete diagram by a certain value? (shrink it to half the size?)

Comment: @Bananr You can put the `forest` inside a `\scalebox` e.g. `\fbox{\scalebox{.5}{\begin{forest}...\end{forest}}}`. However, it will make the tree too small, in my opinion. Your audience will not be able to understand the tree easily and are likely to find it difficult or impossible to read the labels. My advice would be to drop the fractions shown on the edges if you do this as they will not really be legible and will just make it harder to read the other text. (You can always provide the more detailed tree on a handout, for example.)

Comment: Can I manually add fractions or other annotations for a branch if by default these fractions are disabled?

Comment: @Bananr You can use `edge label` for the relevant node.

Comment: @Bananr See edit.