# Allignment of Tikz tree levels

Tags: vertical-alignment, nodes, tikz-trees, tikz-styles

I want to reproduce the following figure.

[image]

And got the following figure with the code given below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, trees, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1cm
, level distance=1.15cm
,  every node/.style = {
shape=rectangle
%                                           ,  rounded corners
, draw=blue!50
, inner sep=1mm
, outer sep=0mm
,  minimum size=2.5cm
, minimum height=8mm
, align=center
, anchor=north
}
,  Trt/.style = {
shape=rectangle
,  rounded corners
, draw=black!90
,  top color=blue!10
,  bottom color=blue!30
, inner sep=1mm
, outer sep=0mm
,  minimum size=2.5cm
, minimum height=8mm
, align=center
, anchor=north
}
,  Th/.style = {
shape=rectangle
,  rounded corners
, draw=black!90
, inner sep=1mm
, outer sep=0mm
,  minimum size=2.5cm
, minimum height=8mm
, align=center
, anchor=north
}
,  Control/.style = {
shape=rectangle
,  rounded corners
, draw=green!90
,  top color=green!10
,  bottom color=green!30
, inner sep=1mm
, outer sep=0mm
,  minimum size=2.5cm
, minimum height=8mm
, align=center
, anchor=north
}
,  Comment/.style = {
shape=rectangle
,  draw=none
,  inner sep=0mm
,  outer sep=0mm
,  minimum height=5mm
,  align=right
}
,  level 1/.style = {
sibling distance=35mm
}
,  level 2/.style = {
sibling distance=20mm
}
,  level 3/.style = {
sibling distance=20mm
}
,  edge from parent fork down
,  edge from parent/.style = {
draw
,   semithick
, -latex
}
,
]



% Theraspist 1
\node[Trt]   (Trt)   {Treatment}
child {node[Th] (Th1) {Theraspist 1}
child {node (S1) {Subject 1}
child {node (S1Y)  { $\textrm{T}_{1}$,  $\textrm{T}_{2}$, $\textrm{T}_{3}$}}
}
}
child {node[Th] (Th2) {Theraspist 2}
child {node (S2) {Subject 2}
child {node (S2Y) {$\textrm{T}_{1}$,  $\textrm{T}_{2}$, $\textrm{T}_{3}$}}
}
};

%from bottom to top
\node[Comment] (L1)    [left=5.0mm of S1Y] {Level 1};
\node[Comment] (L2)    [left=5.5mm of S1] {Level 2};
\node[Comment] (L3)    [left=5.5mm of Th1] {Level 3};


% Theraspist 2
\node[Control]   (Control)   [right=45mm of Trt] {Control}
child {node (S3) {Subject 3}
child {node (S3Y)  { $\textrm{T}_{1}$,  $\textrm{T}_{2}$, $\textrm{T}_{3}$}}
}
child {node (S4) {Subject 4}
child {node (S4Y) {$\textrm{T}_{1}$,  $\textrm{T}_{2}$, $\textrm{T}_{3}$}}
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I wonder how to align the levels vertically as given in the first figure. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just move  down  nodes `S3` and `S4` with `yshift=-1.55cm`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, trees, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 1cm
, level distance=1.15cm
, every node/.style = {
  shape=rectangle
%                                           ,  rounded corners
, draw=blue!50
, inner sep=1mm
, outer sep=0mm
, minimum size=2.5cm
, minimum height=8mm
, align=center
, anchor=north
}
,  Trt/.style = {
  shape=rectangle
, rounded corners
, draw=black!90
, top color=blue!10
, bottom color=blue!30
, inner sep=1mm
, outer sep=0mm
, minimum size=2.5cm
, minimum height=8mm
, align=center
, anchor=north
}
,  Th/.style = {
  shape=rectangle
, rounded corners
, draw=black!90
, inner sep=1mm
, outer sep=0mm
, minimum size=2.5cm
, minimum height=8mm
, align=center
, anchor=north
}
,  Control/.style = {
  shape=rectangle
, rounded corners
, draw=green!90
, top color=green!10
, bottom color=green!30
, inner sep=1mm
, outer sep=0mm
, minimum size=2.5cm
, minimum height=8mm
, align=center
, anchor=north
}
,  Comment/.style = {
  shape=rectangle
, draw=none
, inner sep=0mm
, outer sep=0mm
, minimum height=5mm
, align=right
}
,  level 1/.style = {
  sibling distance=35mm
}
,  level 2/.style = {
  sibling distance=20mm
}
,  level 3/.style = {
  sibling distance=20mm
}
,  edge from parent fork down
,  edge from parent/.style = {
draw
,  semithick
, -latex
}
,
]



% Theraspist 1
\node[Trt]   (Trt)   {Treatment}
child {node[Th] (Th1) {Theraspist 1}
child {node (S1) {Subject 1}
child {node (S1Y)  { $\textrm{T}_{1}$,  $\textrm{T}_{2}$, $\textrm{T}_{3}$}}
}
}
child {node[Th] (Th2) {Theraspist 2}
child {node (S2) {Subject 2}
child {node (S2Y) {$\textrm{T}_{1}$,  $\textrm{T}_{2}$, $\textrm{T}_{3}$}}
}
};

%from bottom to top
\node[Comment] (L1)    [left=5.0mm of S1Y] {Level 1};
\node[Comment] (L2)    [left=5.5mm of S1] {Level 2};
\node[Comment] (L3)    [left=5.5mm of Th1] {Level 3};


% Theraspist 2
\node[Control]   (Control)   [right=45mm of Trt] {Control}
child {node[yshift=-1.55cm] (S3) {Subject 3}
child {node (S3Y)  { $\textrm{T}_{1}$,  $\textrm{T}_{2}$, $\textrm{T}_{3}$}}
}
child {node[yshift=-1.55cm] (S4) {Subject 4}
child {node (S4Y) {$\textrm{T}_{1}$,  $\textrm{T}_{2}$, $\textrm{T}_{3}$}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution with the `forest` package. The comment nodes on the side are done separately.

Some notes:

1. When setting styles in `\tikzset`, you don't need to repeat the same options for all styles. You could create a basic style and then only write the differing ones, which take precedence over the basic style.
2. No need to specify `shape=rectangle`, that's the default shape. Same as writing `draw=black`, just `draw` will have the same result.
3. For the same reason as 2, you don't need to load the library `shapes`. I also replaced `arrows` with `arrows.meta` that is the new library. The other one is still supported but deprecated.
4. I created a `phantom` node, so you see two trees, but it's actually one. The two colored nodes have a parent.

### Output

[image: example image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning}

\tikzset{%
    every node/.style={%
        draw=blue!50,
        inner sep=1mm,
        outer sep=0,
        minimum size=2.5cm,
        minimum height=8mm,
        align=center,
        anchor=north,
    },
    Trt/.style={%
        rounded corners,
        draw=black!90,
        top color=blue!10,
        bottom color=blue!30
    },
    Th/.style={%
        rounded corners,
        draw=black!90
    },
    Control/.style={%
        rounded corners,
        draw=green!90,
        top color=green!10,
        bottom color=green!30,
    },
    Comment/.style={%
        draw=none,
        inner sep=0mm,
        outer sep=0mm,
        minimum height=5mm,
        align=right
    },
}

\forestset{myst/.style={%
    for tree={%
        parent anchor=south, 
        child anchor=north,
        l sep=1.15cm,
        edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge},-{Latex}] 
         (!u.parent anchor) |- ($(!u.parent anchor)!.5!(.child anchor)$) -| (.child anchor)
         \forestoption{edge label};}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest} myst,
[,phantom
    [Treatment, Trt
        [Therapist 1, Th
            [Subject 1, tier=word
                [{$T_1$, $T_2$, $T_3$}]
            ]
        ]
        [Therapist 2, Th, name=lvl3
            [Subject 2, tier=word, name=lvl2
                [{$T_1$, $T_2$, $T_3$}, name=lvl1]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [Control, Control,
        [Subject 3, tier=word
            [{$T_1$, $T_2$, $T_3$}]
        ]
        [Subject 4, tier=word
            [{$T_1$, $T_2$, $T_3$}]
        ]
    ]
]
\node[left=3cm of lvl1, Comment] {Level 1};
\node[left=3cm of lvl2, Comment] {Level 2};
\node[left=3cm of lvl3, Comment] {Level 3};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just slightly redesign of your MWE and @salim bou answer code. For nicer appearance of tree diagrams:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz,preview]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, trees}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, minimum width=22mm, inner sep=2mm, 
                     font=\sffamily},
       Trt/.style = {rounded corners, draw=blue!90,
                     top color=blue!10,  bottom color=blue!30},
        Th/.style = {rounded corners, draw=black!90},
     Other/.style = {draw=blue!50},
     Cntrl/.style = {rounded corners, draw=green!90,  
                     top color=green!10,  bottom color=green!30},
 sibling distance = 33mm, 
   level 1/.style = {level distance = 16mm},
   level 2/.style = {level distance = 12mm},
    edge from parent fork down,  
    edge from parent/.style = {draw, semithick, -latex}
                    ]
% Theraspist 1
\node[Trt]   (Trt)   {Treatment}
    child {node[Th] (Th1) {Theraspist 1}
        child {node[Other] (S1) {Subject 1}
            child {node[Other] (S1Y)  {T$_1$,  T$_2$, T$_3$}}
                }
            }
    child {node[Th] (Th2) {Theraspist 2}
        child {node[Other] (S2) {Subject 2}
            child {node[Other] (S2Y) {T$_1$,  T$_2$, T$_3$}}
                }
            };
% comments, from bottom to top
\node   [left=of S1Y] {Level 1};
\node   [left=of S1]  {Level 2};
\node   [left=of Th1] {Level 3};

% Theraspist 2
\node[Cntrl,right=45mm of Trt]   (Control)  {Control}
        child {node[Other,yshift=-12mm] (S3) {Subject 3}
            child {node[Other] (S3Y)  {T$_1$,  T$_2$, T$_3$}}
            }
        child {node[Other,yshift=-12mm] (S4) {Subject 4}
            child {node[Other] (S4Y) {T$_1$,  T$_2$, T$_3$}}
            };
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `justtrees.sty` which is a wrapper for **forest** which makes it very easy to specify aligned nodes to the left and the right of the tree. It also means that we don't have to worry about either using multiple trees or using a phantom root. This uses version 0.05 of the wrapper. If you are interested in using it, let me know and I can give you an up-to-date copy. Right now, the wrapper is still experimental, but it seems to be working quite well so far.

---

To use the wrapper, we just say

```
\usepackage{justtrees}
```

This allows us to use the following environment:

```
\begin{justtree}{<preamble, possibly empty>}
  <specification of tree in bracket notation>
\end{justtree}
```

Within the tree specification, we can use the following styles to set the contents of aligned nodes to the left and/or right of the tree. The specified content will be aligned with the current level.

```
left just=<content of node aligned to left of tree>
right just=<content of node aligned to right of tree>
```

The following style can be specified to adjust the formatting of the aligned nodes.

```
just format=<style for aligned nodes>
```

So, we can write something like the following.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
```

Load the wrapper.

```
\usepackage{justtrees}% v 0.05
```

Use the current arrows library, `arrows.meta`.

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
```

Define the styles, using a couple of basic styles to avoid unnecessary repetition and making it easier to implement consistent adjustments to the styling.

```
\tikzset{
  basic/.style={
    inner sep=1mm,
    outer sep=0mm,
    minimum size=2.5cm,
    minimum height=8mm,
    align=center,
    semithick,
  },
  basic round/.style={
    basic,
    rounded corners,
  },
  blue box/.style={
    basic,
    draw=blue!50,
  },
  Trt/.style = {
    basic round,
    draw=black!90,
    top color=blue!10,
    bottom color=blue!30,
  },
  Th/.style = {
    basic round,
    draw=black!90,
  },
  Control/.style = {
    basic round,
    draw=green!90,
    top color=green!10,
    bottom color=green!30,
  },
}
```

Now for the tree. First, start the environment and the first argument.

```
\begin{justtree}{%
```

Now make changes to the defaults to customise the look of this particular tree.

We want these to be applied to the whole tree.

```
    for tree={
```

Change the format of the edges from parents to children.

```
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
```

Set the anchors for the edges from parents to children.

```
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
```

Adjust the format of the edges.

```
      edge={-LaTeX, semithick},
```

Set a default format for nodes within the tree which will be overridden as needed.

```
      blue box,
```

Increase the distance between levels a bit.

```
      l sep+=5pt,
```

Shift the aligned nodes on the left a little to increase the distance between these and the nodes within the tree.

```
      just format={xshift=-2.5pt}
    },
```

Now for a change which we need to delay. We'll change the alignment of terminal nodes before the tree is *packed* (see **forest**'s manual for details).

```
    before packing={
```

We want to apply this to the whole tree. That is, we want to *consider* applying it to all nodes.

```
      for tree={
```

But we'll only actually touch the terminal ones i.e. those with no children. These, we will put on a single `tier` to ensure that they are all aligned horizontally. We need a name for this `tier`. We'll use `terminal`.

```
        if n children=0{tier=terminal}{}
      }
    }
```

End the preamble and close the mandatory argument to the `justtree` environment.

```
  }
```

Now specify the tree in **forest**'s bracket syntax. Note that it is OK that we appear to have two roots here, something which would not be allowed in the plain `forest` environment.

The left top-most node gets a special format, `Trt`, its children get another, `Th`.

```
  [Treatment, Trt, for children={Th}
```

Here we specify the first aligned node to the left, `Level 3`.

```
    [Therapist 1, left just=Level 3
```

The next left aligned node.

```
      [Subject 1, left just=Level 2
```

The last left aligned node.

```
        [{$T_1, T_2, T_3$}, left just=Level 1]
      ]
    ]
    [Therapist 2
      [Subject 2
        [{$T_1, T_2, T_3$}]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

The right top-most node gets a special format.

```
  [Control, Control
```

The remainder of this sub-tree is straightforward. Nothing special here. If we wanted, we could use `left just` here instead of above. The left-aligned nodes would still be automatically placed in the same locations.

```
    [Subject 3
      [{$T_1, T_2, T_3$}]
    ]
    [Subject 4
      [{$T_1, T_2, T_3$}]
    ]
  ]
```

Close the `justtree` and `document` environments.

```
\end{justtree}
\end{document}
```

And we are done.

[image: tree with aligned nodes to left]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{justtrees}% v 0.05
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  basic/.style={
    inner sep=1mm,
    outer sep=0mm,
    minimum size=2.5cm,
    minimum height=8mm,
    align=center,
    semithick,
  },
  basic round/.style={
    basic,
    rounded corners,
  },
  blue box/.style={
    basic,
    draw=blue!50,
  },
  Trt/.style = {
    basic round,
    draw=black!90,
    top color=blue!10,
    bottom color=blue!30,
  },
  Th/.style = {
    basic round,
    draw=black!90,
  },
  Control/.style = {
    basic round,
    draw=green!90,
    top color=green!10,
    bottom color=green!30,
  },
}
\begin{justtree}{%
    for tree={
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      edge={-LaTeX, semithick},
      blue box,
      l sep+=5pt,
      just format={xshift=-2.5pt}
    },
    before packing={
      for tree={
        if n children=0{tier=terminal}{}
      }
    }
  }
  [Treatment, Trt, for children={Th}
    [Therapist 1, left just=Level 3
      [Subject 1, left just=Level 2
        [{$T_1, T_2, T_3$}, left just=Level 1]
      ]
    ]
    [Therapist 2
      [Subject 2
        [{$T_1, T_2, T_3$}]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  [Control, Control
    [Subject 3
      [{$T_1, T_2, T_3$}]
    ]
    [Subject 4
      [{$T_1, T_2, T_3$}]
    ]
  ]
\end{justtree}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm trying to find the `justtrees.sty` package, but two web search engines, a search on CTAN, and a search on TeX.sx found only this answer `http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247720/5699` which contains v0.01. Could you provide a link to the latest version (0.5 or 0.07, from the comments I've seen).

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron Please see http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30295014#30295014 for version 0.08. I can't decide what to do with this, to be honest. From time to time somebody asks for it but I've no idea whether it works for them or not and I would now probably design it differently .... It is minimally updated for the current version of Forest in the sense that it should work. Please let me know if you find any bugs or whatever.